# php_excel07- how to replicate the properties of one row to next row

Tags: php, phpexcel

My application needs Export to xlsx, so i am using php_excel07. Everything is working fine but i am facing small issue, which is lik this: "I want to replicate the properties of row to next row". For Ex if i have row num 1 with predefined height, width, color and borders,etc..then these same properties of row1 have to be replicated to next row i.e, row2..Is there anyway to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your styling: manually read the appropriate properties from the first row/the cells of the first row, and set them in the second. There is no explicit method provided to clone styles from one row to another.

However, if all the cells in the first row are identical, you can apply that style to a range of cells rather than having to do it individually.

Personally, I build style arrays that I can then replicate where I need them.

The worksheet methods:

```
duplicateStyle()
duplicateStyleArray()
```

and the style method:

```
applyFromArray()
```

can probably be of some use.